# Returning Null Value instead of 'NOT UPDATED'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT  top 1 'Uploaded_Date' =   
 CASE isnull(Uploaded_Date,'')  
 WHEN Uploaded_Date THEN 'NOT UPDATED' 
else uploaded_date 
  END     
FROM ABC
```

or

```
SELECT  top 1 'Uploaded_Date' =   
 CASE isnull(Uploaded_Date,0)  
 WHEN 0 THEN 'NOT UPDATED' 
else uploaded_date 
  END     
FROM ABC
```

when the column Uploaded_date is null or empty it is supposed to return NOT UPDATED but instead NULL is get returned..!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just `select ISNULL(Uploaded_Date, 'NOT UPDATED')`

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 'Uploaded Date' = CASE WHEN Uploaded_date IS NULL THEN 'No Updated' ELSE Uploaded_date

Comment: is it a real null or the string null that get returned?

Comment: Hi Sushil, thanks for the response but its still  I'm getting null value instead of 'No Updated' while using your query

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2008 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Real Null value @Fredou

Comment: @qxg its not working

Comment: Does 'its not working' mean it doesn't handle empty correctly? If so you can write `ISNULL(NULLIF(Uploaded_Date, '')), 'NOT Updated')`. It may not be fast, but short.

Comment: yes, Off course..!

Comment: `CASE isnull(Uploaded_Date,null) WHEN null ` - What are you trying to do there? If Uploaded_Date is already null why would you replace it with null?  and `WHEN null` will never match anything anyway. as `= NULL` is never true.

Comment: I used like   CASE isnull(Uploaded_Date,'' )  
  when Uploaded_Date then 'NOT UPDATED' but its not working its coming up with empty column..! @qxg

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not sticking with that query but I even tried that like CASE isnull(column_name,0), CASE isnull(column_name,'') and CASE isnull(column_name,null)

Comment: what is the result of select convert(varbinary, Uploaded_Date) from abc ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
   SELECT  top 1 
   CASE WHEN (Uploaded_Date IS NULL or LTRIM (RTRIM (isnull(Uploaded_Date,'')))='NULL')
        THEN CAST('NOT UPDATED' AS VARCHAR(50))
        ELSE CAST(uploaded_date AS VARCHAR(50)) END  as  'Uploaded_Date'
     FROM ABC
```

Comment: Hi Unnikrishanan, thanks for the response the above query is also returning  empty column..!

Comment: What is the data type of the column uploaded_date?

Comment: the data type I used is varchar(50)

Comment: Ok.. So there is a chance of null string in your column.. Try with the updated script.

Comment: Sorry to say this, again I'm stuck up with the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an `int` value to `Uploaded_Date` which is a `varchar(50)`.Instead of storing `int` `0` store `'0'` i.e varchar and compare in the `case` statement.It should work.

```
   SELECT  top 1 'Uploaded_Date' =   
     CASE isnull(Uploaded_Date,'0')  
     WHEN '0' THEN 'NOT UPDATED' 
    else uploaded_date 
      END     
    FROM ABC
```